# How to pass the argument to tasks in airflow dag

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to execute python scripts and some shell commands in airflow dag based on a dictionary.

The code where I'm trying to achieve this is below. Here I don't know how to pass the value of the dictionary "key" as the input to the python script - params.x doesn't work, throws error saying "x" is undefined. Can you help me fixing this?

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    'retries': 0,
}

mydict = {
  1: "name1",
  2: "name2",
  3: "name3"
}

INDEX=1
with DAG('test_dag', default_args = default_args, schedule_interval=None, catchup=False) as dag:
    for x,y in mydict.items():        

        run_test_1 = BashOperator(
                task_id=f'task1_{y}',
                bash_command="python /path-to-the-script/simple_scirpt.py '{{ params.x }}'"
        )           

        run_test_2 = BashOperator(
                task_id=f'task2_{y}',
                bash_command="echo '{{ params.x }}'"
        )
        
        run_test_1 >> run_test_2
        INDEX += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`params` in Airflow enables you to pass in values from outside the DAG, e.g. when you trigger a DAG manually you can pass additional keys/values, which can then be used in your DAG via `params`. See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/params.html for more information.

In your code, you have a hardcoded dictionary so there's no use for `params`. You can use variables `x` and `y` in your code as such:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    'retries': 0,
}

mydict = {
  1: "name1",
  2: "name2",
  3: "name3"
}

INDEX=1
with DAG('test_dag', default_args = default_args, schedule_interval=None, catchup=False) as dag:
    for x,y in mydict.items():        

        run_test_1 = BashOperator(
                task_id=f'task1_{y}',
                bash_command=f"python /path-to-the-script/simple_scirpt.py '{x}'"
        )           

        run_test_2 = BashOperator(
                task_id=f'task2_{y}',
                bash_command=f"echo '{x}'"
        )
        
        run_test_1 >> run_test_2
        INDEX += 1
```